# Is it true that blowing cannot be used for laminar flow control? Why?

Tags: aerodynamics, drag, laminar-flow

[Aerospace Engineering Desk Reference, page 505](https://books.google.mv/books?id=8K6Y8MhqbKgC&pg=PA505&dq=blowing%20laminar%20flow%20control&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqj8TS14bqAhX37XMBHfxvB5gQ6AEwAHoECAMQAg#v=onepage&q=blowing%20laminar%20flow%20control&f=false)

> Tangential blowing can only be applied to the prevention of separation...The flow caused by blowing tends to be very vulnerable to laminarturbulent transition...

Is this true? Why? Is it because of the high speed of the blowing jet? Is it not possible to use a slow-speed (but faster than the local flow) jet to circumvent this?

Comment: Yes, it is. What would a slow speed jet accomplish? Laminar flow means that all airflow is in one direction without crossflow. Any jet of different speed will disturb that calm, orderly flow, causing turbulence. And adding energy will only be possible with a faster jet.